# iOS - Finding a complex object in an array

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ipad

I have an object from a NSObject class that I call "brand" and has the following properties:

```
.name
.number
.site
```

at a given time, dozens of these objects are stored on a NSMutableArray, something like:

```
object 1
object 2
object 3
object 4
...
```

I would like to be able to retrieve a given object from the array by its number. Not the index of the object on the array but the number property of the object (get object
that has the number property equal to 10, for example).

I know that NSArrays have smart methods for retrieving stuff but I don't know them deeply cause I use this rarely. Is there any way to retrieve that object from the array without having to iterate thru all objects on the array and check each object's number property?

Can you guys help? thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would recommend `NSPredicate`. You could do it with something like this, assuming `listOfItems` is your array containing your `NSObject`'s with said properties.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"number == 10"];
NSArray *filtered = [listOfItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Your filtered results, any numbers matching `10` will now be in the `filtered` array. If you want to cast back to your object, you can do something like this:

```
YourObject *object = (YourObject*)[filtered objectAtIndex:0];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 12):

```
NSUInteger indexOfObject10 = [myArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    MyObject *object = (MyObject *)obj;
    return [object.number == 10];
}];

MyObject *object10 = myArray[indexOfObject10];
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using block extensions to NSArray that let you "talk" to them more naturally and write less code. Something in the lines of the Smalltalk Collections jargon:

- detect:
- select:
- inject:into:
- etc.

In your case I would use:

```
MyObject* theObject = [myArray detect:^(MyObject* each){
     return each.number == 10;
}];
```

Here you have a possible implementation for that extension to NSArray

```
typedef BOOL (^BlockPredicate) (id element);

-(id) detect:(BlockPredicate) predicateBlock{
     for (id each in self) {
        if (predicateBlock(each)) {
            return each;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

I find this kind of tools really helpful. I hope you find them useful too.

Comment: what happens if the array contains more than one object with the same number?

Comment: This implementation will 'detect' and return the first one. If you wish to find all the instances with the same number, you could use select:.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
NSObject *retrieveObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
retrieveObject.number = 1;

NSObject *anObject = [yourMutableArray objectAtIndex:[yourMutableArray indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:testObject]];
```

First, I create an object with the same number as an object in the array that I want to retrieve (in this case "1"). In the next line, I assume that when you retrieve it you want to assign it's value to another object, so I retrieve it by using the standard `objectAtIndex:` method with the index parameter being another method, the `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:` method, with that method's parameter being the `retriveObject` object. So what this does is it looks in the array for the first object identical to retrieveObject (meaning they'd have the same number) and returns that object's index, and then passes that value into the `objectAtIndex` method.

Hope this helps!